# Android Studio 4.1.3 can't build apps targeting API level 30

Tags: android, android-studio, android-11

I have some apps (live wallpapers) targeting API level 30.
And after updating AS to 4.1.3 I'm getting errors for overridden methods available in this API level:

```
F:\...\Wallpaper.java:133: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @/Override
        ^
```

```
F:\...\Wallpaper.java:136: error: cannot find symbol
            super.onZoomChanged(zoom);
                 ^
  symbol: method onZoomChanged(float)
```

The code uses `onZoomChanged` API which was introduced in API 30 and compiled just fine with older AS: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/wallpaper/WallpaperService.Engine#onZoomChanged(float)

```
@Override
public void onZoomChanged(float zoom) {
    renderer.setZoom(zoom);
    super.onZoomChanged(zoom);
}
```

`build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.androidworks.livewallpapermuseum"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':LiveWallpaperTulipsCommon')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.8.0'

    def appcompat_version = "1.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appcompat_version"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:$appcompat_version"
}
```

When this code is commented out, app is compiled and runs but obviously lacks this Android 11 feature for updating zoom level of wallpaper.

Apps were build just fine on older AS, I even have them published.

I've tried:

- invalidating AS caches
- cleaning project and gradle caches
- reinstalling AS (yes even after uninstall and install problem persists)

**Update**.

Issue was caused by upgrading gradle plugin to 4.1.3. Obviously since these changes were introduced to gradle files it won't work with any AS version. After revering it back to 4.0.1 I can build app.

Comment: So what is your `compileSdkVersion`? That's what controls what APIs are available.

Comment: Try File > Invalidate Cache / Restart

Comment: Try creating a scrap project that references this method, and see if that project builds. If it does not, you might try posting an issue to the Studio issue tracker, including that scrap project plus screenshots, etc.

Comment: @Torge I've tried invalidate/restart.
@ianhanniballake I've attached full `build.gradle`.